# Mint 17.1 - installation reverts to Grub - UUI

Tags: linux-mint, uuid

I'm attempting to install Mint 17.1 and have succesfully used Universal USB Installer to create a bootable USB stick. When booting up Mint the pleasing loading screen fails to make an appearance and instead the Grub menu is shown.

How should I proceed to install Linux Mint on this machine?

I have attempted the same proces using YUMI but in this case the machine reverts to the BIOS settings instead of loading Mint / Grub from the USB stick.

To clarify, I'm not intent on dual booting with Windows 8 but replacing the Windows installation with Mint.

Comment: Do you already have grub installed in your HD, is that the menu that keeps showing up? Have you booted from a USB successfully before?

Comment: No, grub is currently not installed on the HD.
I have booted from a USB stick before, not on this machine though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning to dual-boot with windows 8 you should see [this question on askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) with peculiarities about pre-installed windows 8 & UEFI, has pages of instructions & tips.

Could be problems with UEFI if your computer has that, see this Ubuntu help page (Mint's based on Ubuntu, the Ubuntu techniques usually work) for more info: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

It may be booting in EFI mode so you see a screen like this:
[image]

Setting the computer to **boot using Legacy mode** might work, if your BIOS/UEFI has that setting that you can find. Or use an EFI image, it gets complicated so definitely see the help pages above. Secure boot may only work with the 64-bit versions also, but disabling secure boot &/or EFI should work.

**OR** the USB may not have been created successfully, you could try using a different too to create it, the [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) that I think you tried usually works, but there are others to try too:

- [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)
- [Linux Live USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download)
- [Win32DiskImager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager)

If you can install GRUB to your USB I prefer the "copy the whole ISO file" method here: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-multiple-iso-from-usb-via-grub2-using-linux/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've configured the BIOS (UEFI util v2.10) Secure Boot setting to boot "other OS" instead of "Windows EUFI mode" but the net result is the same - the GRUB CLI pop ups when booting. 
Secure Boot state is enabled and cannot be altered by the user.

Comment: You're trying the 64-bit version? Apparently 64-bit works best (or only works) with Secure boot - as the first linked dual-boot Q says, regardless of whether or not you actually want to dual-boot most of the steps to run & install are the same

Comment: Yes, I'm attempting to install the 64bit version of Mint 17.1

Comment: I have attempted to install Mint using the instructions provided but the install fails at running Mint from the USB stick, the grub menu shows up instead.

Comment: Maybe a screenshot of the menu that shows up would help to see what's going on?